# iText7 RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy How to get the fontname and fontsize of the found text

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, itext7

I tried text replacement with iText7 on C#. I can only get the content and rectangle of the search text using RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy, and I want to get both the font and size of the text. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement [ITextExtractionStrategy](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/dotnet/8.0.0/interfacei_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_canvas_1_1_parser_1_1_listener_1_1_i_text_extraction_strategy.html) to do this (there are other methods you'll need to implement. Just keeping it brief here).

```
class CustomTextExtractionStrategy : ITextExtractionStrategy
{
    public void EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
    {
        if (type is EventType.RENDER_TEXT)
        {
            if (((TextRenderInfo)data).GetText().Equals("here I can match the text"))
            {
                data.GetGraphicsState().GetFont();
                data.GetGraphicsState().GetFontSize();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[GetFont()](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/dotnet/8.0.0/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_canvas_1_1_canvas_graphics_state.html#a5f27e3fe3a79193fad282dc2f10bb6e9) will contain [PdfFont](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/dotnet/8.0.0/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_font_1_1_pdf_font.html), and [GetFontSize()](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/dotnet/8.0.0/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_canvas_1_1_canvas_graphics_state.html#aeb1e9397ee3d31dc789c666ebf0d25a7)... The font size (well, duh).

You can also use the [TextRenderInfo](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/dotnet/8.0.0/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_canvas_1_1_parser_1_1_data_1_1_text_render_info.html) bit to do your pattern matching.

And this is how you'd register this custom Extracter (one of many ways. Don't forget to iterate over all pages, and whatnot):

```
CustomTextExtractionStrategy customTextExtractionStrategy = new CustomTextExtractionStrategy();
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(DEST));
PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(customTextExtractionStrategy);
parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfDocument.GetFirstPage());
```

I should add that I am not a C# developer, so sorry if this looks ugly/there are more elegant ways to use the language.