# How to avoid spurious spaces in words when reading PDF using iText for .NET

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Using iText7 (v8.0.0) I am attempting to parse a (non-PDF/A) PDF.  The code is as follows:

```
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser;

var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("TestFile.pdf"));

var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(1);

var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page);
```

All is well in terms of the output except that certain words in the output text have spurious spaces in them.  I understand that this is to do with the way text is rendered into the PDF.  The `GetTextFromPage` method has an overload that takes a text extraction strategy; I tried both the default strategy implementations `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`  and `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` but neither dealt with the issue.

I am guessing that I need to define my own text extraction strategy but it isn't very obvious how to go about doing this.

(In case readers are interested, I tried the same with IronPDF and that was no better.)

Comment: hard to reply with some example PDF, but I've recently replied something that involved custom text extraction https://stackoverflow.com/a/76620874/1566339 (you can see the Interface you need to implement from it). (I'm on mobile, sorry for the lazy temporary reply)

Comment: Many thanks for the above comments.  I have subsequently been in touch with iText sales and their pricing is off the charts for commercial use, so I am abandoning this approach.  A big shame as it seems that reading PDFs is something it is impossible to do with a decent open source implementation.  (iText's open source is copy-left, so not suitable for my application.)

Comment: Often such spaces appear in text extraction is that one PDF mechanism to separate words can also be used as a mechanism to achieve kerning and text extractors have to apply heuristics to determine which is which. Also there are documents in which a space and a glyph are printed (nearly) in the same position while in the output of text extractors they follow one another.

Comment: Can you share a sample PDF file?

Comment: If you're dropping the idea of using iText to do text extraction, maybe have a look at the PdfPig and their wiki (https://github.com/UglyToad/PdfPig/wiki/Document-Layout-Analysis). It's an open source and free (Apache 2) project. Disclaimer: I'm a contributor to the project

Comment: Thank you for the pointer @bld (and apologies for the delay in responding).  I did try PdfPig but it was giving me back each letter as a separate word.  I will give it another go when I come back to this, although it wasn't clear that the project was being actively maintained - hopefully it is.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have subsequently decided not to use the iText library due to the licensing costs, as I managed to fix the issue, I thought I'd share my findings.  Aside from the many helpful comments above, I got the base information I needed from answers to this question: [how can we extract text from pdf using itextsharp with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398483/how-can-we-extract-text-from-pdf-using-itextsharp-with-spaces).

Here is the easiest way to address this issue.  Add the following class:

```
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener;

internal class MyStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
{
    protected override bool IsChunkAtWordBoundary(TextChunk chunk, TextChunk previousChunk)
    {
        var chunkLocation = chunk.GetLocation();
        var previousChunkLocation = previousChunk.GetLocation();
        var chunkCharSpaceWidth = chunkLocation.GetCharSpaceWidth();

        float dist = chunkLocation.DistanceFromEndOf(previousChunkLocation);
        if (dist < -chunkCharSpaceWidth || dist > chunkCharSpaceWidth / 1.5f)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I found the value `1.5f` gave the best results (the default is 2.0f); your mileage may vary.

It is then a simple matter to supply the custom strategy to the processing thus:

```
var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, new MyStrategy());
```

Note that if you need to do the same thing with the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` you pretty much have to copy and paste the entire original class, as it uses a bunch of `private` members which you don't have access to when inheriting.