# Testing the presence of a string in a PDF file with iText 7 (8.0)

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I'm currently doing some basic benchmark (generate, split, merge, read, compress) to choose a C# Pdf library to use in my project.

I'm trying to extract text from a pdf File and checking if the text contains a string. The file is a generated invoice with exploitable text lines, so OCR can be used but not necessary.

WITH DYNAMIC PDF by example the documentation is clear

```
PdfDocument inputDocument = new PdfDocument(RessourcesBenchmark.PDF_MERGE_PAGE_TO_APPEND_PATH);
var text = inputDocument.GetText();
```

How to achieve this in C# with iText ? iText documentation is weirdly done, you either read all the API, or you read ebooks or examples on their site and those are always very specific. I found [this SO article](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-extract-text-and-anchor-information-from-a-pdf) about annotations and read the pdf as a stream.

If someone has an example or a snippet to guide me, I already spend 2 hours on this.

After my benchmark I will ask to publish at least the code to github because all these libraires documentation is not always obvious.

Comment: _"extract text from a pdf File"_ - the problem with this is: there is no such thing as _"a PDF file"_. That abomination of a file format has so many variations, that you will have to either be very specific about what you mean by "text" or jump several hoops to include each and every edge case.

Comment: here's a quickie on another reply I did previously: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76620874/1566339

Comment: @Fildor I will be more accurate in my question,  good point.

Comment: @AndréLemos I posted my implementation, if you have recommendations about some points I will gladly edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

With some of the posts in stack overflow and the help of André Lemos I managed to find a solution. I will post the full implementation here.

As in the other post we have to create a custom class implementing the `ITextExtractionStrategy` interface. Maybe an abstract class in iText could spare us this step.

```
    //To be able to extract text from our pdf document
    public class CustomTextExtractionStrategy : ITextExtractionStrategy
    {
        private string textResult { get; set; }

        public CustomTextExtractionStrategy()
        {
        }

        public void EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
        {
            if (type is EventType.RENDER_TEXT)
            {
                textResult += ((TextRenderInfo)data).GetText();
                
            }
        }

        public string GetResultantText()
        {
            return textResult ?? string.Empty;
        }

        public ICollection<EventType> GetSupportedEvents()
        {
            return new List<EventType>{
                EventType.BEGIN_TEXT,
                EventType.RENDER_TEXT,
                EventType.END_TEXT,
                //EventType.RENDER_IMAGE,
                EventType.RENDER_PATH,
                EventType.CLIP_PATH_CHANGED };
        }
    }
```

Then we can use this class as a parameter in a PdfCanvasProcessor to process text and by getting back the CASTED eventListener

```
public class ITextBenchmark
{
    public ITextBenchmark()
    {
    }
    // Our text extracting method
    public IEnumerable<string> TextExtraction()
    {
        var pdftext = new StringBuilder();
        CustomTextExtractionStrategy customTextExtractionStrategy = new CustomTextExtractionStrategy();
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(RessourcesBenchmark.PDF_MERGE_PAGE_TO_APPEND_PATH));
        PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(customTextExtractionStrategy);

        //Process all the pages of the document
        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
        {
            parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfDocument.GetPage(i));

            // Here we have to extract data from the event listener contained in the parser. 
            var eventResult = (CustomTextExtractionStrategy)parser.GetEventListener();
            pdftext.Append(eventResult.GetResultantText());
            parser.Reset();
        }

        if (pdftext.ToString().Contains("*"))
        {
            return new List<string> { $"The pdf contains '*'" };
        }
        else
        {
            return new List<string> { "Unavailable" };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to retrieve text from a PDF using C# *without* using a custom text extraction strategy. It is simple to do using NET Core, all that's needed is the `itext7` nuget package. (A link to a working solution can be found [here](https://www.debugandrelease.com/how-to-scan-a-pdf-for-text-using-csharp/)).

```cs
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener;

namespace ScanTextInPDFs
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string executingDirectory = AppContext.BaseDirectory;

            byte[] bytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync($"{executingDirectory}PDFs\\Brochure.pdf");
            string textToFind = "Lorem ipsum";
            bool foundText = false;

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                using PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(memoryStream);
                using PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);

                for (int page = 1; page <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); page++)
                {
                    PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDocument.GetPage(page);
                    string pageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfPage, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());

                    if (pageText.Contains(textToFind, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                        foundText = true;
                }
            }

            if (foundText)
                Console.WriteLine($"Found '{textToFind}' in the pdf.");
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"Did not find '{textToFind}' in the pdf.");
        }
    }
}
```